# Android: Persist object across activities

Tags: android

I've got an object that I use to interact with various things. The object itself is initialized in my first activity and used in all subsequent activities. What's the best way to make it "public" to all activities?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a class that extends Application and hold the instance there.

```
class MyApp extends Application{
    private Object obj;
    public Object getObject(){
         return obj;
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity

```
MyApp ma = (MyApp)getApplicationContext();
Object o = ma.getObject();
```

You can read more about the Application class on the android developer website: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class MyStorage {
        private static MyStorage ourInstance = new MyStorage();
        public static MyStorage getInstance() {
            return ourInstance;
        }
        private MyStorage() {
        }
        public HashMap<String,Object> storage=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

//put data
MyStorage.getInstance().storage.put("mykey", obj);

//get data
Object obj=MyStorage.getInstance().storage.get("mykey");
```

Comment: Mind to add some explanation?

Comment: create class MyStorage in your project then whenever that you need to store an object use [MyStorage.getInstance().storage.put("mykey", obj);] and whenever you want to read it use [Object obj=MyStorage.getInstance().storage.get("mykey");]